# How to design a single interface to save different Collections in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, collections, interface

I have multiple collections like:

```
TFooList = TObjectDictionary<string,TFoo>;
TBarList = TObjectDictionary<string,TBar>;
....

TRoot = class
   value : string
end;

TFoo = class(TRoot)
...
end;

TBar = class(TRoot)
...
end;
```

And I have an interface/class that could save or load collections:

```
ISave = interface
  procedure Save( TDictionary<string, string> );
  function Load: TDictionary<string, string>;
end;
```

**Note that the interface expects a key/string pair collection in order to work properly.**

I implemented some ISave classes in order to load/save the collection to/from file or databases:

```
TDbSave = class( TInterfacedObject , ISave )
   ....
end; 
iSave := TDbSave( ConnString )

TFileSave = class( TInterfacedObject , ISave )
   ....
end; 
iSave := TFileSave( fileName );
```

So, the last piece would be inherit from each collection and create the save/load methods to "translate" each collection into/from TDictionary(string, string)

```
    TFooListSavable = TFooList;
      procedure Create( save_load : ISave );
      procedure Save;
      procedure Load;
      ....
   end;

   procedure TFooListSavable.Save
      // 1. create a  TDictionary<string, string>
      // 2. load the dictionary above with my collection translating
      //    each Foo object into a string
      // 3. call save_load.Save( dictionary );
   end;    
   procedure TFooListSavable.Load
      // 1. create a  TDictionary<string, string>
      // 2. call save_load.load to load it 
      // 3. Move over the collection and translate string into TFoo and
      // 4. AddOrEquals each TFoo created into TFooListSavable.
   end;
```

So, I have two problems with this approach:

1) The interface that save or load expects a string value from the Collection and, although all the objects in each collection inherit from a class that has this string defined, I don't know how to transform a collection like `TDictionary<string,TFoo>` into a `TDictionary<string,string>` without resorting to the code above (which will duplicate the collection in order to pass it to `iSave` object).

2) I feel that, although I can replace `iSave` objects changing the way the collections would be saved/loaded without changing the collections themselves, I don't know if it is the best approach to save/load collections that keep related objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are going about this the wrong way.

`ISave` should not have any concept of any `TDictionary` at all.  It should just expose methods for reading/writing basic data types (integers, strings, etc).  Let `TFooListSavable` and `TBarListSavable` decide how to serialize their respective `TDictionary` data however they want, calling the `ISave` methods as needed.

Even better would be if `TFooListSavable` and `TBarListSavable` pass `ISave` to each individual `TFoo`/`TBar` and let them serialize their own data members directly.

For example, something like this:

```
type
  ISerialize = interface
    function HasData: Boolean;
    procedure StartWriteCollection;
    procedure StartWriteItem;
    procedure FinishWriteCollection;
    procedure FInishWriteItem;
    procedure WriteBoolean(value: Boolean);
    procedure WriteInteger(value: Integer);
    procedure WriteString(const value: String);
    ...
    procedure StartReadCollection;
    procedure StartReadItem;
    procedure FinishReadCollection;
    procedure FinishReadItem;
    function ReadBoolean: Boolean;
    function ReadInteger: Integer;
    function ReadString: String;
    ...
  end;

  TRoot = class
  public
    value : string;
    constructor Create; virtual;
    procedure Save(Dest: ISerialize); virtual;
    procedure Load(Src: ISerialize); virtual;
  end;

  TBaseList<T: TRoot, constructor> = class(TObjectDictionary<string, T>)
  public
    procedure Save(Dest: ISerialize);
    procedure Load(Src: ISerialize);
  end;

  TFoo = class(TRoot)
  public
    myint: Integer;
    ...
    procedure Save(Dest: ISerialize); override;
    procedure Load(Src: ISerialize); override;
  end;
  TFooList = TBaseList<TFoo>;

  TBar = class(TRoot)
    mybool: Boolean;
    ...
    procedure Save(Dest: ISerialize); override;
    procedure Load(Src: ISerialize); override;
  end;
  TBarList = TBaseList<TBar>;

  TDbSerialize = class(TInterfacedObject, ISerialize)
    ...
  end; 

  TFileSerialize = class(TInterfacedObject, ISerialize)
    ...
  end; 

  procedure TBaseList<T>.Save(Dest: ISerialize);
  var
    pair: TPair<string, T>;
  begin
    Dest.StartWriteCollection;
    for pair in Self do
    begin
      Dest.StartWriteItem;
      Dest.WriteString(pair.Key);
      TRoot(pair.Value).Save(Dest);
      Dest.FinishWriteItem;
    end;
    Dest.FinishWriteCollection;
  end;

  procedure TBaseList<T>.Load(Src: ISerialize);
  var
    Cnt, I: Integer;
    key: string;
    value: T;
  begin
    Self.Clear;
    Src.StartReadCollection;
    While Src.HasData do
    begin
      Src.StartReadItem;
      key := Src.ReadString;
      value := T.Create;
      try
        value.Load(Src);
        Self.Add(key, value);
      except
        value.Free;
        raise;
      end;
      Src.FinishReadItem;
    end;
    Src.FinishReadCollection;
  end;

  procedure TRoot.Save(Dest: ISerialize);
  begin
    Dest.WriteString(value);
  end;

  procedure TRoot.Load(Src: ISerialize);
  begin
    value := Src.ReadString;
  end;

  procedure TFoo.Save(Dest: ISerialize);
  begin
    inherited;
    Dest.WriteInteger(myint);
  end;

  procedure TFoo.Load(Src: ISerialize);
  begin
    inherited;
    myint := Src.ReadInteger;
  end;

  procedure TBar.Save(Dest: ISerialize);
  begin
    inherited;
    Dest.WriteBoolean(mybool);
  end;

  procedure TBar.Load(Src: ISerialize);
  begin
    inherited;
    mybool := Src.ReadBoolean;
  end;
```

Comment: You've got a point saying that each class (TFoo, TBar) should have the responsability to translate themselves into strings. 
But don't you think that the load/save procedure of the collection is a little bit "streaming-oriented"? I think it would be hard to code a database version (TDbSerialize), wouldn't it?

Comment: @MarcosCunhaLima no, I don't think it would be hard at all. What I showed is just an example. If needed, you can add additional methods to `ISerialize` so the DB implementation can create a new record for each collection item, then the `Write` methods can update the record columns as needed, then commit when finished. Or create a new blob for the entire collection to be written to. Whatever you need.